# Reverse proxy with mod_rewrite

Tags: reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite

I am trying to achieve this:

subdomain.mydomain.com/customerA -> internalserver1/application/
subdomain.mydomain.com/customerB -> internalserver2/application/

This broght me to the login page of the application (on mobile only and with no images):

```
ProxyPass /customerA http://internalserver1/application
ProxyPassReverse /customerA http://internalserver1/application
ProxyPass /customerB http://internalserver2/application
ProxyPassReverse /customerB http://internalserver2/application
```

[Reading here](https://serverfault.com/questions/350012/apache-proxypass-missing-images?newreg=b432acc68d734f01b68eaa1b9b163dc1) made me add this:

```
ProxyPass /application http://internalserver1/application
ProxyPassReverse /application http://internalserver1/application
```

This made images available, but I don't see how to apply this to multiple servers.

I think I need to use mod_rewrite, but I don't get how.
Also, I don't get why the above only works on mobile and not on desktop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite won't do you any good.

The best option would be to configure your backend servers to serve the HTML with the correct base URL (`/customerA/` instead of `/application/`).

If this is not possible you can use [`ProxyHTMLURLMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#proxyhtmlurlmap) from mod_proxy_html to rewrite the HTML before it is served.

This will however add latency to your requests and load to your proxy server.

Comment: Thanks Gerald, unfortunately I cannot change the application name. I tried to use 'ProxyHTMLURLMap' without success, so far. I forgot to mention the application is based on Tomcat, I am now exploring [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/proxy-howto.html)

Comment: The key is to set the correct Context path  in the tomcat server config.

Comment: Would it make more sense to use `mod_jk` instead of `mod_proxy`? It is both promising and confusing.